# Who is Hindu. What is Hinduism?

Tags: dharma

Humanity, Service to the needy, and Humble ness are essential qualities in any living being who is born as a human being. My doubt about Hinduism is how it is helping the Hindus in developing above three quality es.

Comment: If you see the body of this question it's quite different from that question. I had initially close voted by seeing the title but later retracted my vote because I thought it's giving me the scope of answering with something useful which I can't post under the other question.@Archit

Comment: @Rickross yeah I just realised. I think we can tell the asker to edit the title slightly and vote to reopen. **Mr. Balaji**, your title doesn’t match with the question in the body, hence it has resulted in confusion and the question being closed as duplicate. Requesting you to please edit the title to reflect what the body is asking and please do contribute an upvote to the answer below, if you like it. The answer is covering all aspects asked by you. Thus, if the answer is satisfactory, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark ✔️ so that the community knows that it’s the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

> My doubt about Hinduism is how it is helping the Hindus in developing
> above three qualities

Hindu scriptures repeatedly instruct all the human beings to have the qualities you have mentioned and much more.

For example see the following verses:

> Manu Smriti 7.40. Through a want of modesty many kings have perished,
> together with their belongings; through modesty even hermits in the
> forest have gained kingdoms.
>
> 7.41. Through a want of humility Vena perished, likewise king Nahusha, Sudas, the son of Pigavana, Sumukha, and Nemi.

The above emphasize the fact that even Kings, who are all-powerful, will perish if they are lacking in humility what to say of ordinary men.

Service to the poor and needy is a duty for all householders. It's a degraded householder who doesn't help the needy and the poor.

> The father, the mother, the preceptor, the wife, the children, the
> poor people, the dependants, the incomers and the guests, are spoken
> of as the Poshyas (i.e., those who should be supported . (29)
>
> Kinsmen, relatives, those suffering from diseases, who have none to
> look after them, those who seek refuge, and others having no means,
> are also spoken of as the Poshyas (30)
>
> To support the Poshyas, is
> the most excellent expedient for attaining to the celestial region. By
> oppressing them, one goes to hell. Therefore one should support them
> with care. (31)
>
> One desiring for lordly powers, should make gifts unto the poor, the
> helpless and the learned. By making gifts unto unworthy persons,
> people are born dependant on another's fortune. (35)
>
> **Daksha Smriti; Chapter 2**

So, the scriptures of Hinduism are full of such instructions. It now depends on us whether we are willing to follow them or not.

Comment: Means? @Archit    ...

Comment: I think these instructions are to be a Human but not a Hindu.

Comment: @Mr_Green I am not answering the title but a question found in the body viz: "My doubt about Hinduism is how it is helping the Hindus in developing above three qualities" -- I am showing how Hinduism (Hindu scriptures) is helping Hindus (those who follow Hindu scriptures) in developing the mentioned qualities.